# Get best match in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I want to get results from MySQL query, sorted by best match. This means that when I a table like this:

```
+--------+
| Field  |
+--------+
| X01234 |
| 001234 |
| 01234  |
| XT1234 |
+--------+
```

and want to search for `$str='012'`, the desired output should be like

```
01234
001234
X01234
```

To get this, the only way I found is using this UNION query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE field LIKE '$str%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE field LIKE '%$str%'
```

Is there a better way of selecting best match for searched string?

Comment: Why do you need the `UNION`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the double `%` in the second query. Please check it. The first query will select all records starting with searched string while the second query will select all records containing the searched string

Comment: The first query in the union is redundant.

Comment: Nope. It helps selecting best match. `UNION` will remove duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's what you want

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE field LIKE '%$str%'
ORDER BY INSTR(field,'$str'),field
```

You also can use `INSTR` instead `LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE INSTR(field,'$str')>0
ORDER BY INSTR(field,'$str'),field
```

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3b410/1

Comment: Awesome!! It was such a long time I was looking for a solution like this!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE field LIKE '$str%' ORDER BY my_table